# How to get selected radio button data in AngularJS (ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get selected row data(id, name) with radio button. To be specific;

```
<tr data-ng-repeat=" list in listTypes">
    <td>{{list.TaskId}}</td>
    <td>{{list.Comments}}</td>
    <td>{{list.RecordDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.StartDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.DueDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.AssignTo}}</td>
    <td>{{list.AssignBy}}</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
        <input type="radio" name="switch-radio1" checked="" value="0" ng-value="true" >
        <span></span>
    </label></td>
</tr>
```

When selected radio button, I should get the datas(`taskId`, `comments`), which is selected row. Which function should I use it? (specially I need JS part)
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ng-model` for your checkbox which can be used as following:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat=" list in listTypes">
    <td>{{list.TaskId}}</td>
    <td>{{list.Comments}}</td>
    <td>{{list.RecordDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.StartDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.DueDate}}</td>
    <td>{{list.AssignTo}}</td>
    <td>{{list.AssignBy}}</td>
    <td>
         <label class="switch">
             <input type="radio" name="switch-radio1" ng-model="list.selected" ng-change="onTaskSelect(list)">
         </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now your controller code will look something like this:

```
$scope.onTaskSelect = function(task) {
    // access your whole task object here.
    console.log(task.selected);    // will be true when you select it or else false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to assign a ng-model to your radio button and change your ng-value to something like the list.TaskId

```
<input type="radio" name="switch-radio1" ng-model="selectedItem" checked="" value="0" ng-value="list.TaskId" >
```

Now that you have the list.TaskId you can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to look for the data in listTypes

Comment: Shashank Agrawal answer is cleaner

Comment: Right. Thats what I need. Thank you for your answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way better than other. when we use "ng-model" don't need the name attribute
and because of the use of "$parent" I think to access a single model to play the role of the name attribute and also binding data.
Therefore, because of the following quotes, as each item has a scope, we must have a higher level to achieve the single model that we define.

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. ***Each template instance gets its own scope***, where the
>   given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index
>   is set to the item index or key.
>   https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
>
> $scope Properties : $parent Reference to the parent scope.
>   https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent

in template HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in listTypes">
        <td>{{list.TaskId}}</td>
        <td>{{list.Comments}}</td>
        <td>{{list.RecordDate}}</td>
        <td>{{list.StartDate}}</td>
        <td>{{list.DueDate}}</td>
        <td>{{list.AssignTo}}</td>
        <td>{{list.AssignBy}}</td>
        <td>
             <label class="switch">
                 <input type="radio"  ng-model="$parent.rdoModel" ng-value="item" >
             </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 <button type="button" ng-click="Ok(rdoModel)">OK</button>
```

in Angularjs controller script :

```
$scope.rdoModel={};
$scope.Ok = function(item){
var data = item ; // access to all data of list item
};
```